# How to add many columns to the table at once in DolphinDB database

Tags: sql, database, dolphindb

Is there a way to add many columns at once like this?

```
t=table(1..6 as id,(today()-5)..today() as tm);
update t set feature_1001..feature1030=float(),feature_2001..feature2020=float()
```

I wrote the following method, which can be implemented, but it feels a bit complicated. Is there an easier way?

```
for(x in 1001 .. 1030) t["feature_"+x] = float()
for(x in 2001 .. 2030) t["feature_"+x] = float()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
t["feature" + string(1001 .. 1030 join 2001 .. 2030)] = loop(x->float(), 1..60)
```